# Attempt to connect to OrientDB with Elixir using the binary protocol returns invalid Session-ID

Tags: orientdb, elixir

I'm trying to connect to OrientDB (2.1 rc5) with Elixir (1.0.5). Both are running on my local machine, I've written the following code as a first attempt to connect:

```
{:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.connect(to_char_list("localhost"), 2424, [{:packet, :raw}, :binary], 30_000)
a_r = receive do
{:tcp, ^socket, <<_succes, version>>} ->
  msg = <<2 :: 8>> <> #REQEST_CONNECT
    <<-1 :: 32>> <> #Negative Session-ID
    <<byte_size("Test") :: 32>> <> "Test" <> #Driver-name
    <<byte_size("0.0.1") :: 32>> <> "0.0.1" <> #Driver-version
    <<version :: 16>> <> #Protocol-version
    <<byte_size("") :: 32>> <> "" <> #Client-ID
    <<byte_size("Binary") :: 32>> <> "Binary" <> #serialization-impl
    <<1 :: 8>> <> #use token
    <<byte_size("root") :: 32>> <> "root" <> #user-name
    <<byte_size("orient") :: 32>> <> "orient" #usr-pwd

  :gen_tcp.send(socket, msg)
  receive do
    msg -> msg
  after
    10000 -> :error1
  end
after
  10000 -> :error2
end
```

After running this code, I get a result with the first byte set to 0, but the Session-ID is still -1. A token is always returned, whether or not I set it to 0 or 1. If I send a positive integer as Session-ID, the connection is rejected, which also happens if I send an invalid password.

I've compared my code with the [orientjs driver](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs/blob/master/lib/transport/binary/connection.js), and checked whether all fields are present in the right order with the correct formatting in the [manual](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Network-Binary-Protocol.html), but I don't see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields in the data you're sending are in the correct order. To be poignant, you're getting the correct version when you do `<<_success, version>>` kind of out of luck, as OrientDB only writes the version as a short (2 bytes) at connection time, without the first byte distinguishing between OK or error responses. Since the version is small (likely 31), it gets written as `<<0, 31>>` with two bytes, so your `version` variable has the correct value. Use `<<version :: 16>>` instead :).

But that's not the problem, what you're asking is OrientDB-related, no Elixir involved. OrientDB always sends `-1` as the session id back when a client connects, so the behaviour you're seeing is expected. Also, the token is always returned (whether you say you want it or not): if you don't want it, an empty token is returned. If you ask for it, it could still be empty (meaning the server doesn't support token-based auth).

You have to send a session id of `-1` at connection time (actually, a negative integer) because you still don't have a session id and yes, passing a positive session id results in the TCP connection being dropped if the session id doesn't exist.

So, you did nothing wrong :) The response you get will look something like:

```
<<0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 32, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0>>
```

which means:

- `0` - OK response
- `<<255, 255, 255, 255>>` (`-1` as an int32) - session id of -1 because of the new connection
- `<<0, 0, 32, 102>>` (`8294` as an int32) - the session id for the **new session**, you have to use this for subsequent requests on the same connection
- `<<0, 0, 0, 0>>` - the token (empty in this case as `0` int32 is the length of the token bytes)

All that said, a binary driver for OrientDB written in Elixir is going to be open sourced in the next few days (I know because I wrote it :P), just FYI.

Comment: Thanks for the very informative answer, however, the token is still equal to <<0, 0, 0, 0>> regardless of setting the use-token parameter to 1 or 0 (or 127). So, I'm sending the right message, but somehow I'm not getting a token?

Comment: @Theemuts probably you have token-based auth disabled on the server. You have to manually enable it in the server XML configuration. You can have a look at this [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/graphdb/config/orientdb-server-config.xml#L75-L85).

Comment: Sigh, yes, that solved it... I really need to learn to study the manual better, thanks!